# Mnist Digit Recogniser gives wrong answer when run on own handwritten digits. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, mnist

I am a beginner and I made up the Mnist Digit Recogniser and then tried to test it out on my own handwritten digits but everytime it gives a wrong answer. Could someone help and tell me why is that the case :

Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/sa7890722/MACHINE-LEARNING-AND-NEURAL-NETWORKS/blob/master/Untitled1.ipynb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in your data, the images you are loading are inverted from the colors that mnist uses. Mnist has the digits on a black background while being white themselves. However, in your data, the digits are black on a white background. Your model hasn't seen digits with a white background so it performs poorly. Try doing `1-img` and predict on the result and it should work.

Comment: 1 - img just means to invert the image. Of course, this should be done after scaling your pixel values to be between 0 and 1. Otherwise, do 255 - img. Inverting the image causes white pixels to be black and black pixels to be white.